# zipline error. No module named zipline

Tags: python, virtualenv, zipline

I installed zipline package via Enthought Cantopy. Now I try to run a script using it in command prompt, but get error `ImportError: No module named zipline`.

I also tried to run the same code using IPython, with the same output.

I think it is related to python virtual environments, but don't know how to fix that.

Comment: What is the output of `$ which python`

Comment: Which python installation did Enthought install the library into?

Comment: Did you source the activate script first?

Comment: Maybe you can find zipline by brute force:  `find / | grep zipline`

Comment: command prompt and Power Shell do not recognize "which" or "grep" comand.

Comment: here is output of python command



`Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`


So I have 2.7 version of python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was in the version of python I have. I have 32-bit python and Enthought Cantopy with 64 bit python, installed `zipline` package was under 64 bit python while command prompt was using 32 bit version. Installing 64 bit python fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

These are the Requirements/ Steps to Make Zipline Work:

1. Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express
2. Download and install python 3.4
3. Download zipline from github and Extract in C:/
4. Set Anaconda as project interpreter
5. Since zipline is compatible with Python 3.4, you need to create an environment with Python 3.4
6. Run this command in console of IDE:
   `$conda create -n python34 python=3.4 anaconda`(replace py34 with the location of python34 folder)
7. Now run this command in console:
   `$activate python34` #Activates the python 3.4 environment
8. `$pip install -e C:\GitHub\zipline` (Directory where you extracted zipline)
9. Ingest data from quandl with below command
   `$zipline ingest`

Hope this helps others who visit this page!

Answer (score 0):

The latest Zipline-Trader version was released. For stable version `pip install zipline-trader` For more info follow [docs](https://zipline-trader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for installation.